# Finding the 'ultimate resolution' of an ANN

Tags: classification, training, regression

I want to use a neural network to predict the refractive index of a solution. My thinking is, instead of immediately training on many samples, I will first find the 'ultimate resolution' of the network given the experimental apparatus I am using. What I mean is I will make two different solutions which have refractive indices near the middle of the range of which I am interested. Then I will train the network to classify these two solutions based on reflectance measured from the solution. If it works, say with at least 95% accuracy, then I will make two different solutions in which the difference in refractive index is smaller than before. I will repeat this until the ANN classifies, say below 95%.

Will this method of finding the 'resolution' by classification extrapolate well to regression with many more training examples?

Comment: What is a "refractive index of a solution"? Are you talking about [the refractive index of a material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index)?

Comment: I am measuring the refractive index of a solution based on reflectance data. I'm confused why your confused, do you need me to clarify what a solution is?

Comment: Well, not everyone may be familiar with your terminology, but, nevertheless, could help, so it may be a good idea to explain certain terms.

Comment: Solution is a solute dissolved in a solvent. Reflectance meaning I will put the solution in the apparatus and shine light on it and measure the reflected light.